# fix special character in filename

Tags: bash, directory, filenames

Playing around with some scala I forgot to use `path = path.replaceFirst("^~", System.getProperty("user.home"))` e.g. directly wrote a csv file to `~/stuff/foo.csv`
unfortunately this resulted in:

```
02 22 Nov 19:59 ~
```

e.g. a folder with ~ in the name. How can I remove / rename that folder without messing up `~/`

Comment: Prefix relative (`./~`) or absolute path (`/path/to/~`) to your tilde file or as show by Jim quote tilde to prevent bash expanding `~`to your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in single quotes. You can move it to another name before deleting it.

```
$ mv '~' foo
```

Comment: Perhaps use `rm -i` or `mv -i` (prompt before doing anything) to make sure you're doing the right thing.